# How to overload the init() function in cfscript

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

This example is what I was trying to do, but ColdFusion says `routines can only be declared once. Can ColdFusion do something like this?

```
/**
* @hint Handles vehicles 
*/
component Vehicle
{

    this.stock = "";
    this.year = "";
    this.make = "";
    this.model = "";

    public Vehicle function init()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public Vehicle function init(string stock)
    {
        this.stock = stock;
        //Get the year, make model of the stock number of this vehicle
        return this;
    }

    public string function getYearMakeModel() 
    {
        var yearMakeModel = this.year & " " & this.make & this.model;
        return yearMakeModel;
    }

}
```

Oddly, if I take out the first `init()`, I can use either `new Vehicle()` or `new Vehicle(stocknumber)` and it calls `init(string stocknumber)` either way but this isn't the behavior I want...

Comment: It is not possible to use routine over loading with ColdFusion. But is possible for a single function to work with different argument sets(`required=false`) .

Comment: ... and modify the single function to react acordingly based on the arguments passed.

Comment: @RRK can you post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use routine over loading with ColdFusion. But is possible for a single function to work with different argument sets (`required=false`). That opens up a lot of ways you can use the same function to serve different purposes.

Example, the below function should serve the purpose of both constructor functions you were trying to implement.

```
public Vehicle function init(string stock=''){
  if(len(trim(arguments.stock))){
    this.stock = arguments.stock;
  }
  return this;
}
```

Comment: Reference: [".. You cannot redefine or overload a function. If a function definition is active, ColdFusion generates an error if you define a second function with the same name."](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/writing-and-calling-user-defined-functions/creating-user-defined-functions.html). Though not sure why they make the distinction of "active" ;-)